# Spring Boot : How to generate new access token once it gets expired?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I am implementing JWT token in microservice based architecture.
How can I generate new access token once it gets expired in spring boot?

Comment: Redirect your request to login page when your token gets expired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `refresh_token` and `access_token` after login success, when `access_token` is expired, use `refresh_token` to create new `access_token`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your description is not clear. For your question, just generate it like the first one.